# typescript: type string is not assignable error?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a simple `Fonts` file I am importing with just info right now that contains `Arial` but will contain others later on.

**Fonts.ts**

```
interface Font {
    [key: string]: {
        'full': string,
        'trial': string
    }
}

interface FontList {
    [key: string]: Font
}

export const FONT_LIST: FontList = {
    'Arial':
        {

            'Regular': {
                'full': 'blahblah',
                'trial': 'blahblah'
            },
            'Bold': {
                'full': 'blahblah',
                'trial': 'blahblah'
            },

        },
}
```

---

In a function, I am trying to get the value based on their entitlement

```
import { Fonts } from './Fonts'

function foo(postscriptName:string, style: string) {
     
    const entitlement = "full";

    const selectedFont = FONT_LIST[postscriptName][style][entitlement];

    return selectedFont;
}
```

For `selectedFont`, I am getting a TS error of: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ family: string; style: string; postscriptName: string; }'`

to debug, I even tried `selectedFont = FONT_LIST['Arial']['Bold']['full];` to ensure values are there but I am getting the same error.
I am expecting to get back "blahblah".

Comment: Where are you declaring selectedFont? You are assigning it here, but not declaring it.

Comment: forgot the `const` declaration, sorry...edited it

Comment: Where does the type `{ family: string; style: string; postscriptName: string; }` come from?

Comment: Declare `function foo(postscriptName:string, style: string): string { … }` if that's the type you're expecting back, and it should locate the mistake better